# Disconnecting slots from signals

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

PySide and PyQt employ Qt signal-slot mechanism with which we can connect any/multiple signals to any/multiple slots as far as the trasmistted data types match.

The signalling object has some knowledge of the receiving slots, e.g. knows their number via method `receivers` or the signal can disconnect from the receiving slots via its `disconnect` method.

My problem relates to the oposite direction - e.g. does a slot know to which signals it is connected? Can a slot disconnect from the signals?

UPDATE: So why I am asking this - I have an object that performs some calculation. The calculation is defined by a user editable Python expression. The expression is parsed and necessary data sources are identified from this... The calculation object (acts as a slot) then connects to these data sources (they act as signals) and once the data sources produce/update a value, this fact is signalled to the slot and the expression is reevaluated. And when the expression is changed by a user, it needs to be parsed again and disconnected from the existing signals (i.e. data sources) and connect to new data sources. You can imagine it is something like a formula in Excel that is connected to other cells.

I know there are a few ways to work around this, e.g. keeping track of connections manually (well, this is extra work) or deleting the expression object and creating a new one everytime it is changed (seems not good enough, because user might want to trace back the calculation data sources and this will not help). But I was curious if this can be solved purely using simple signal-slot mechanism. In other words, I am not interested in any workarounds... I know of them and will use them I signals-slots will not help here. :)

Comment: I don't think so. However you can track connections and disconnections manually (for example, using a wrapper of `QObject::connect`).

Comment: I think there must be something, because when a receiving object is deleted, the signal must be notified that one of its receivers is dead to stop sending signals to it. But I have not found anything in the docs.... Of course, keeping the track manually is my other alternative. However I would like to avoid making double work if Qt could do this for me automatically.

Comment: I think you are asking wrong question. Please explain what problem are you trying to solve, do not ask how to fix your idea of solutions to some mysterious problem. This is quite common mistake when asking for help. Why you need to know where slot is connected? Maybe in this case you need temporary disconnect signal to prevent recursion? To prevent possible recursion there is `blockSignals` method.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain my intentions.

Comment: You can save `QMetaObject::Connection` objects returned by `QObject::connect` and use them in [QObject::disconnect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#disconnect-3). It's not so much extra work.

Comment: @ Pavel: I am not sure what you mean - I checked `QObject::connect` and found it returns bool in Qt/C++ as well as in PySide. http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QObject.connect

Comment: The QObject::connect returns bool in qt4.8 but  QMetaObject::Connection in qt5. Regardless, why doesn't disconnect method avalaible in both at versions work for you? Looks like if you did obj1.connect (obj2, signal) you can also do obj2.disconnect (obj1, signal).

Answer (score 3):

The approach you propose forces a very close relationship between the concrete data widgets and the calculation engine. You mingle UI with the calculations. This makes it much harder than it needs to be.

What you could try instead is the model-view approach. The model would be a simple implementation of `QAbstractTableModel`. The view would be the individual data-entry widgets mapped to the model's cells using `QDataWidgetMapper`. The calculation engine would access only the model, completely unaware of how the model is modified by the widgets. This make life easier.

The calculation object can connect to the model using just one `dataChanged` signal and it will be notified of changes to any of the variables. You can easily pass both the value and the variable name by having two columns in the table.

The implementation of the model can be very simple, you can have a list of strings for the variable names in the first column, and a list of variants for the second column. The model must correctly emit the `dataChanged` signal whenever `setData` is called, of course.

Comment: I think this is a total overkill. :) There are much simpler workarounds, which I mentioned. Btw. I have not said anything about UI, widgets etc. Signals/slots are mechanism bound to QObject not just to QWidget. My widgets are in another layer, which I did not even touch in my question.

Comment: @VL.K. You've asked how to cleanly map a data source to a calculation engine. I've shown you how it might be done. It works great, I use this approach widely and it's very easy to deal with. It may well be less code than any other solution, and much easier to maintain. Loose coupling between software elements is considered to be a good engineering practice

Comment: @VL.K. The widgets are optional, it doesn't matter what modifies the data. The deal is that you don't need to have the calculation engine deal with a multitude of variable-dependent connections. That's bad design. With a data model, there's only one signal-slot connection for `dataChanged`, and your engine only needs to hold a pointer to the model. It's much easier on the calculation engine. It's also very easy to troubleshoot the model's contents: you just attach it to a `QTableView`.

Comment: @VL.K. If your receiver object needs to wrangle its own signal/slot connections and it needs to know what objects it's attached to, you're probably doing it wrong. And I think you are.

Comment: @VL.K. The engine also can trivially look up the model indices by searching on the variable name column. So it only needs to know the symbolic variable names, and it can perform the lookup once at setup time and store the `QModelIndex` in its symbol table. By going this way you'll probably shrink your code. A minimal implementation of a table model that you need here is less than a screenful of code.

Comment: Well, this must be a misunderstanding. I explicitly mentioned I am not looking for workarounds. Actually I have a workaround now that just takes some 15 rows altogether (including some blank spaces to make it more readable) and does not use heavy objects such as QAbstractTableModel etc. And yes, it uses just one signal slot connection. What I was asking was if a slot can disconnect from signals. Well, signals can disconnect slots, why not the oposite way? I appreciate your help but it does not answer the question.